# the bake button is not where it should be

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image: i was following a tutorial for baking and the option is simply not there]

I was trying to bake a displacement map into the actual map following

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=94&v=McALCOr39rY&feature=emb_title
for how to do it but I can't find any bake options. please help

Here is the save file for anyone that would like to check problems with the mesh or the UV:[image]

I have seriously no idea.

Comment: Did not look in depth into your file tested it out etc. but if you just go to the shading tab (at the top), the Bake button appears.

Comment: Hello :). @WhatAMesh is probably right. Different workspaces sometimes 'forget' to load some UI elements. Switching to another workspace, or creating a new one should help.

Comment: @WhatAMesh, I tried going into shading, didn't work. any idea what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The baking option in the rendering properties tab is not in the Eevee rendering engine.

Selecting cycles rendering engine shows the baking tab for me in 2.82.7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit > Operator Search > Bake* and done